# Adding an element to a multidimensional array which is already defined in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm building a simple shopping cart without a database, just using an array.

I can add the item to the shopping cart which it has the name and price. I want to be able to add more elements such as quantity at the point when I update the shopping cart.

This is my working code that displays name and price.

```
$_SESSION['cart'] = array($products[$itemid]);
```

$itemid will be the index of an array that contains the name and price.

I've tried several ways to add an element, which have failed. How can I add an element at this point?

```
 $_SESSION['cart'] = array($products[$itemid ,'qty' => 1]);
 $_SESSION['cart'] = array($products[$itemid] ,'qty' => 1);
 array_push($_SESSION['cart'], $products[[$itemid, 'qty' => 1]]);
```

Comment: I think you're both confusing one another. It seems most reasonable to think that `$itemid` is an item id (string or number) and `$products[$itemid]` returns an array of item information (with `name` and `price`). Perhaps `$itemid = '123abc'` and `$product = ['123abc' => ['name' => 'foo', price => 10]]` ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the `$products[$itemid]` is an array with name and price as keys try this to add qty to it:

```
$_SESSION['cart'] = array(array_merge($products[$itemid], ['qty' => 1]);
```

Comment: If you've read my answer i wrote that it will only work  if the $products[$itemid] is an array, and im sure that the $itemid is the id of the item being added to the cart and also the $products is an array of items indexed by items ids.

Comment: @Memor-X I understand your point of view, But what I think @Jeremy doesn't need to change the `$products` var and it makes sense products have nothing to do with the qty but `$_SESSION['cart']` does and he needed to to add the qty to `$_SESSION['cart']` array and that's why I used array_merge and if he needed to add more products to the cart he will just change the line to somthing like `$_SESSION['cart'][] = array(array_merge($products[$itemid], ['qty' => 1]);` and nothing will be lost!

Comment: @Memor-X `['qty' => 1]` uses the array syntax that's been available since PHP 5.4. tehplayground uses PHP 5.3 which is ancient. Use https://repl.it/languages/php instead.